# Keyboard remapping in OS X 10.9

Tags: keyboard, macos

Is it feasible to remap my keyboard mapping in OS X Mavericks? For example, I want to swap <kbd>q</kbd> and <kbd>`</kbd> (backticks), since I don't require typing <kbd>q</kbd> too much and like to owe the position to another key, such as backticks. I've used `keyremap4macbook` to change <kbd>:</kbd> and <kbd>;</kbd>, and <kbd>"</kbd> and <kbd>'</kbd> and have no issues on it, but it looks like the app only allows to change on some specific keys like <kbd>;</kbd>, <kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>?</kbd>, <kbd>{</kbd>, etc. and not on those alphabetical keys.

Also, I got some video tutorials to modify those keys, but it doesn't work on Mavericks since the system preferences look a bit different than in the prior versions.

So is it feasible to remap my keys in Mavericks? And how can I modify it?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [PCKeyboardHack](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/pckeyboardhack.html.en "PCKeyboardHack - Software for OS X - pqrs.org")?

Comment: I'm sure keyremap4macbook can do what you need.  Check the manual more closely.  Another option is Ukelele.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way to do this would be to use [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) and just create two macros, one for 'q' which inserts '`' and one for '`' which inserts 'q'

It also does a ton of other awesome stuff and is one of my favorite OS X utilities, but it’s not free (there's a free trial 30 days it’s ~ $35 IIRC).

However, my guess is that you could *also* do it using [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) using the `private.xml` feature under "Misc & Uninstall"

[image]

I am not qualified to explain what needs to be in the private.xml file, however, I can point you to the documentation for
[A simple example of private.xml](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) which shows some examples and explains the format of the file.

There is also a free Mac OS X app [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) which you will probably want to use to help you find the correct key code values.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I can edit the xml file to make any key remapping work in my system.