# Remap Mavericks alt key without external tools

Tags: macos, keyboard

For some reason the way you write an @ symbol doesn't work anymore. I'm on a german keyboard and it used to be ⌥L but now it is ⌃⌥L which is annoying as hell!

Where are these kind of things stored? I just want a .plist or anything and edit it. All these tools are so incredibly annoying!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keyboard remapping in OS X 10.9](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111858/keyboard-remapping-in-os-x-10-9)

Comment: This has been asked and answered here :- http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/111858/keyboard-remapping-in-os-x-10-9

Comment: No these tools don't help me!

Comment: Can you please add some details about what you have tried already and why the linked answer doesn't help you?

Answer (score 2):

#### DefaultKeyBinding.dict

Create `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` and enter

```
{ "~l" = (insertText:, "@"); }
```

This rebinds ⌥L to insert @
`~` = ⌥

Quit and reopen applications for the change to take effect

Comment: great! this is very useful.