# Modify the keyboard opt symbols

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings, shortcut

Is there any way to (or existing program which can) modify the keyboard symbols you get when holding down the option key?

I.e. I want to be able to modify these mappings:

[image]

Comment: modify to what? those are the original you are showing?

Comment: @Buscar웃 to a different assortment of characters/symbols (e.g. greek characters, mathematical symbols, etc).  This is the current mapping (thus I assume default).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this without using external application there is a good answer here

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/130099/46541

DefaultKeyBinding.dict

Create `~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict` and enter

```
{ "~l" = (insertText:, "@"); }
```

This rebinds ⌥L to insert @

```
~ = ⌥
```

Quit and reopen applications for the change to take effect

Some examples of external sources

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/112381/46541