# OSX doesn't recognize a gaming keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, driver, macbook-pro

I want to use [this Genius keyboard](http://www.geniusnet.com/Genius/wSite/ct?xItem=51776&ctNode=3606) with my 2014 MacBook Pro 15".

When connecting the keyboard, the Keyboard Setup Assistant opens, saying that keyboard could not be identified. Then, it asks to press the key on the left of right shift. When I press<kbd>Z</kbd>key three times, it says that the keyboard still could not be identified and asks to chose the type of keyboard manually.

Despite of the answer, keyboard starts working improperly. When I press<kbd>q</kbd> it types <kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd>w</kbd>-><kbd>4</kbd>,<kbd>e</kbd>-><kbd>l</kbd>,<kbd>r</kbd>-><kbd>y</kbd>,<kbd>t</kbd>-><kbd>1</kbd>,<kbd>y</kbd>-<kbd>6</kbd>and so on. When I chose different type of keyboard (ISO/ANSI) nothing changes and the same wrong buttons mapping preserves.

The keyboard itself is working fine on another PC. Other keyboards are working well with this mac.

Maybe there is some software to properly fix usage of gaming keyboards on mac?

Would really appreciate your help to make it work.

Comment: Here's how I saved you 200 rep :p

Comment: were you able to solve the problem?

Answer (score 5):

> Then, it asks to press the key on the left of right shift. When I press 'Z' key three times

Z is on the right of the left Shift key. You sure you pressing the right keys? According to your post you should be pressing the **"/"** key.

Comment: You're so damn left... Hu. I mean, right!

Comment: Oh my precious 200 bounty..:(..lolz!

Answer (score 2):

Xah Lee has an excellent overview of [key remapping solutions](http://xahlee.info/kbd/Mac_OS_X_keymapping_keybinding_tools.html). The best tool for you may be [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/), using the [Custom Setting option](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/112381) (the post refers to KeyRemap4MacBook, which has been renamed to Karabiner).

To do this you may want to use the [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) utility to determine what your Mac is actually receiving. You will then need to specify the desired translation. A handy list of codes is [here](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner/blob/version_10.6.0/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data).

Some fancy keyboards support configurable key mapping that you download into non-volatile memory. There may be a utility for your keyboard (that might only run on Windows) that can make it emulate a standard layout. I would check on that first so then you could easily move it to another Mac.

Answer (score 0):

"x4ly16" is typical of anti-ghosting (n-key rollover) which macOS doesn't support. If you can turn that off, you should get "qwerty" instead. Your link is broken so I don't see what keyboard model you have, but the manual should say which key combo turns that off.